# Tomcat8.5 and Openjdk11 NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cxf.attachment.AttachmentUtil

Tags: java, cxf, noclassdeffounderror, tomcat8.5

I am migrating a Java Application to OpenJDK11 which is running on Tomcat 8.5. Application and tomcat starts withount any problem. With JDK1.8 I don't have any exception or error But when calling application with another Webservice and running tomcat with OpenJDK11 I get following error:

```
02-Apr-2019 13:27:07.225 SEVERE [http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [CXFServlet] in context with path [/ApplicationName] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cxf.attachment.AttachmentUtil
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentInInterceptor.handleMessage(AttachmentInInterceptor.java:55)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:613)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

When I open Eclipse workspace for this application I can also open and see AttachmentUtil class. This class is in jar 'cxf-core-3.3.1' included which depends on ' **org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.3.1:**'

This is my mvn dependeny tree:

```
 --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ XmlBeans ---
 de.somename.rail.sresb.entireXComServer:XmlBeans:jar:2.12.1
 +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.3.1:compile
 |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
 |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:7.0:compile
 |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.3.1:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.0.3:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.4:compile
 |  |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.3.2:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:xsom:jar:2.3.2:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:codemodel:jar:2.3.2:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind.external:rngom:jar:2.3.2:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.sun.xml.dtd-parser:dtd-parser:jar:1.4.1:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-tools:jar:3.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.10.5:compile
 |  |  |  |     \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.10.5:compile
 |  |  |  \- com.sun.xml.bind.external:relaxng-datatype:jar:2.3.2:compile
 |  |  \- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:compile
 |  |     \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1:compile
 |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.3.1:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.3.1:compile
 |  |  |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile
 |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.3.1:compile
 |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:3.3.1:compile
 |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:3.3.1:compile
 |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:3.3.1:compile
 |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:3.3.1:compile
 |  |     \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.1.1:compile
 |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.1:compile
 |  +- com.sun.activation:javax.activation:jar:1.2.0:compile
 |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec:jar:1.1.3:compile
 |  +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.4.0-b03:compile
 |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
 |  \- org.jboss.spec.javax.rmi:jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.6.Final:compile
 +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.0:compile
 +- org.glassfish.main.javaee-api:javax.jws:jar:3.1.2.2:compile
 +- javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
 |  \- javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api:jar:1.4.0:compile
 +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
 +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.1:compile
 |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.1:compile
 |  +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.7:compile
 |  +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8:compile
 |  \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.15:compile
 +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.3.0:compile
 +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.3.0:compile
 +- com.sun.xml.ws:rt:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  +- com.sun.xml.ws:policy:jar:2.7.2:compile
 |  +- org.glassfish.gmbal:gmbal-api-only:jar:3.1.0-b001:compile
 |  |  \- org.glassfish.external:management-api:jar:3.0.0-b012:compile
 |  +- com.sun.xml.stream.buffer:streambuffer:jar:1.5.4:compile
 |  +- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.7:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
 |  +- com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal:resolver:jar:20050927:compile
 |  \- javax.jws:jsr181-api:jar:1.0-MR1:compile
 \- com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:jar:2.3.0:compile
```

Any useful hints are appreciated. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had right the same problem. Adding this dependency helped so far:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

The application works, but I now recieve this warning:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteBufferUtils cannot access class jdk.internal.ref.Cleaner (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.ref to unnamed module @5ce81285
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved this problem after a lean period. Added some missing CXF and Java EE dependencies in pom's of 2 package modules.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>    
</dependency>
```

Comment: I guess this hell waits for some people out there :( But if you want to have a much smoother life, just use the [cxf-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/codecentric/cxf-spring-boot-starter) which provides all those dependencies for you - and brings in so many more features, incl. full support for newer JDKs, generation of all JAX-WS classes out-of-the-box and much more. But thanks for documenting, [we had similar problems](https://github.com/codecentric/cxf-spring-boot-starter/issues/52)...

Comment: What helped in my case was adding missing dependency to "javax.activation" and "angus-activation".
But the original exception was misleading and what helped to debug/find out what is missing, was adding try/catch as near as possible to the the code which was about to call AttachmentUtil class.

Answer (score 2):

`NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cxf.attachment.AttachmentUtil` means that JVM failed to initialize the `AttachmentUtil` class.

Apache CXF 3.3.X should support JDK 11 [as per FAQ](https://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-CanCXFrunwithJDK/Java9+(10,11)?). You want to debug the startup with exception breakpoint on the `NoClassDefFoundError` exception and see what was the root cause. It looks likely a `static` field or block failed to run when loading `AttachmentUtil` class but the root cause was surpressed.

Comment: thank you Karol. But why does it work with JDK 8? I don't have any problem with this Java version

Comment: You won't know until you debug the `AttachmentUtil` class loading on Java 11.

Comment: Ok but I develop on Windows and this application is ony runnable on Linux Suse. I am not able to debug it locally

Comment: I'll try this in maven pom: 

<properties>
<maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

Comment: now I got another NoClassDefFoundError:  com/sun/activation/registries/LogSupport

Comment: `com/sun/activation/registries/LogSupport` is one of the classes that is no longer available after Java 9 project Jigsaw modularized the JVM. `com.sun.*` classes were not supposed to be used in user code and are only available pre Java 9.

Comment: I'm not sure that will run anytime.